How to fetch reviews from Google Business Profile
I am currently in the process of retrieving review data from our Google Business Profile using the most recent documentation and API guidelines available online. Despite following the instructions meticulously, I am consistently encountering a 404 error, which typically signifies that the requested resource is not found on the server. This issue is particularly pressing as our business has accumulated over 2000 reviews. Accessing this data is critical for our analysis and management of customer feedback.
I tried to fetch the reviews using node.js here is the code. Please help me in sorting the issue. Thank You :)
const express = require('express');
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const axios = require('axios');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

// Use constants for credentials
const CLIENT_ID = "";
const CLIENT_SECRET = "";
const REDIRECT_URI = "http://127.0.0.1:3000/authorize";

// Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials
const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, REDIRECT_URI);

// Define the scopes for the authorization URL
const scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage'];

// Generate the authorization URL
const url = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline', // Ensure offline access to get a refresh token
    prompt: 'consent', // Force user to re-consent to ensure refresh token
    scope: scopes
});

// Log the authorization URL
console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', url);

// Variable to store tokens
let accessToken = null;
let refreshToken = null;

app.get('/authorize', async (req, res) => {
    const code = req.query.code; // Get the authorization code from the query parameter
    if (!code) {
        return res.status(400).send('Authorization code not found');
    }

    try {
        // Exchange the authorization code for tokens
        const { tokens } = await oauth2Client.getToken(code);
        oauth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);

        // Log the access and refresh tokens
        console.log('Access Token:', tokens.access_token);
        console.log('Refresh Token:', tokens.refresh_token);

        // Store tokens in variables
        accessToken = tokens.access_token;
        refreshToken = tokens.refresh_token;

        // Check if refresh token is received
        if (!tokens.refresh_token) {
            return res.send('No refresh token received. Please reauthorize by visiting the URL again.');
        } else {
            return res.send('Authorization successful! You can close this window.');
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error retrieving tokens:', error);
        return res.status(500).send('Error during authorization.');
    }
});

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    if (!accessToken) {
        return res.status(401).send('Access token is missing. Please authorize the app first.');
    }

    try {
        // Set the credentials to the oauth2Client
        oauth2Client.setCredentials({ access_token: accessToken, refresh_token: refreshToken });

        // If the access token is expired, refresh it
        if (oauth2Client.isTokenExpiring()) {
            const { credentials } = await oauth2Client.refreshAccessToken();
            oauth2Client.setCredentials(credentials);
            accessToken = credentials.access_token;
            console.log('Access token refreshed');
        }

        // Define account and location IDs
        const accountId = '';
        const locationId = '';

        // Fetch the reviews
        const response = await axios.get(`https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/${accountId}/locations/${locationId}/reviews`, {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`
            }
        });

        console.log("Reviews data: ", response.data);
        
        // Send the reviews data as JSON
        res.json(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching reviews:', error);
        res.status(500).send('Error fetching reviews.');
    }
});

// Start the server
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at http://127.0.0.1:${port}/`);
});



But what's the issue exactly? You're getting a 404 where?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

@Gabriel After successful authentication with refresh token and access token. When i am passing the account id and the placeid of the business i am getting the issue
